# How does Google create the checkmark for its input checkboxes on the form for creating a new Google account?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Scroll to the bottom of the page: https://accounts.google.com/SignUp

The checkbox itself is just CSS - borders, background colors, etc. But I don't see anything in the DOM/CSS that accounts for the actual check *mark*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this css rule in chrome inspect element

```
input[type="checkbox"]:checked::after {
content: url(//ssl.gstatic.com/ui/v1/menu/checkmark.png);
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: -6px;
left: -5px;
}
```

Content links to this image
https://ssl.gstatic.com/ui/v1/menu/checkmark.png

Answer (score 1):

As Joel put in his answer, it appears the CSS links to a content image.

However, offhand I'd guess it's a non-standard chrome specific thing.  Other browsers don't seem to follow this check content thing very well.  Here's a small sample size:

[image]

Comment: Brilliant idea to check it worked in other browsers, I wrongly assumed this was standard CSS.

Comment: I've seen in other google apps, such as gmail, that checkbox appearance holds true in other browsers besides Chrome.  Though, it appears to not be truly a "checkbox" more-like a shimmed up div with similar functionality.  The specific form element on the sign-up page that the question asked about is however a checkbox in the markup for all browsers I tested.